# Second column is not fade sequential effect

Tags: jquery

the items of the second column has the same sequence do not effect the first:

```
var delay = 0;
$('.first-column .item').each(function () {
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        'left':'3%'
    }, 500);

  $('.second-column .item').delay(delay).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        'right':'3%'
   }, 500);
    delay += 400;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dGQNT/)

Comment: >[This](http://jsfiddle.net/dGQNT/3/)< is not an answer, but might help a little. Mike's answer looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over each .first-column .item and increasing the delay by 400 ms each one you animate.

However, you are setting the same animate on all .second-column .item elements each time through the loop.  So they are animating at 0ms, then getting called at 400ms (except they are already faded in), 800ms, etc.

You need to change your looping structure to iterate over each of them separately, or at least call animate on second-column .item one at a time as you go through first-column .item

Answer (score 0):

You're looping incorrectly - you have to loop through both columns simultaneously. Maybe try something like this:

```
var delay = 0,
    x = 0;

$(".coluna .item").each(function(){
    $('.first-column .item').eq(x).delay(delay).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        'left':'3%'
    }, 500);
    $('.second-column .item').eq(x).delay(delay).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        'right':'3%'
    }, 500);    
    delay += 400;
    x++
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dGQNT/2/)

May not be the cleanest solution, but I'll leave that up to you to fix up if need be.